# Merge sets of time - method

Tags: java

I'm trying to merge sets of time. I mean I've something like this. My code works good for single data. How can I do it for n times?

```
BEFORE MERGE: 
[
    {
        "start": "11:00",
        "end"  : "15:00"
    },
    {
        "start": "10:00",
        "end"  : "12:00"
    }
]


AFTER MERGE:

[
    {
        "start": "10:00",
        "end"  : "15:00"
    }
]
```

My code:

```
 public List<ScheduleEntry> merge(ScheduleEntry a, ScheduleEntry b) {

        List<ScheduleEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();

        int durationInMinuteBetweenStarts = parseTimeString(a.getStartTime()) - parseTimeString(b.getStartTime());
        int durationInMinuteBetweenEnds = parseTimeString(a.getEndTime()) - parseTimeString(b.getEndTime());
        int durationInMinuteBetweenStartAAndBEnd = parseTimeString(a.getStartTime()) - parseTimeString(b.getEndTime());
        int durationInMinuteBetweenStartBAndAEnd = parseTimeString(b.getStartTime()) - parseTimeString(a.getEndTime());


        if(durationInMinuteBetweenStartAAndBEnd > 0 || durationInMinuteBetweenStartBAndAEnd < 0) {
            entries.add(a);
            entries.add(b);
        }

        else if(durationInMinuteBetweenStarts <  0 && durationInMinuteBetweenEnds >= 0) {
            String newStart = a.getStartTime();
            String newEnd = a.getEndTime();

            entries.add(new ScheduleEntry(newStart, newEnd));
        }

        else if(durationInMinuteBetweenStarts >= 0 && durationInMinuteBetweenEnds < 0) {
            String newStart = b.getStartTime();
            String newEnd = b.getEndTime();

            entries.add(new ScheduleEntry(newStart, newEnd));
        }

        else if(durationInMinuteBetweenStarts <= 0 && durationInMinuteBetweenEnds <= 0) {
            String newStart = a.getStartTime();
            String newEnd = b.getEndTime();

            entries.add(new ScheduleEntry(newStart, newEnd));
        }

        else if(durationInMinuteBetweenStarts > 0 && durationInMinuteBetweenEnds >= 0) {
            String newStart = b.getStartTime();
            String newEnd = a.getEndTime();

            entries.add(new ScheduleEntry(newStart, newEnd));
        }

        return entries;
    }

    private int parseTimeString(String s) {
        String[] t = s.split(":");
        return Integer.parseInt(t[0]) * 60 + Integer.parseInt(t[1]);
    }
```

I don't know how can I implement it for list of ScheduleEntry :/ Should I sort it and then trying to find answer? Basic idea of above code is checking duration between times and using it designate answer.

Comment: Please include your code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
Please take the [tour](/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic). From that second link: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it." This must not be links to an external service.

Comment: My code? What do you mean? my code is in pasterbin file

Comment: Include the code from pastebin in the question.

Comment: I can't I mean when I want to do this I get "please include more information about code" and...

Comment: *"my code is in pasterbin file"* it should be in the post and please make it a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [new Date and Time API](http://www.baeldung.com/java-8-date-time-intro). Run all the ScheduledTimes in a loop and check for max stop and min start.

```
ArrayList<ScheduleEntries> times = new ArrayList<>();

times.add(new ScheduleEntries(LocalTime.of(8, 00), LocalTime.of(12, 00)));
times.add(new ScheduleEntries(LocalTime.of(11, 00), LocalTime.of(15, 00)));
times.add(new ScheduleEntries(LocalTime.of(9, 00), LocalTime.of(17, 00)));

LocalTime minStart = times.get(0).getStart();
LocalTime maxStop = times.get(0).getStop();

for (ScheduleEntries time : times) {
    if (time.getStart().isBefore(minStart)) {
        minStart = time.getStart();
    }
    if (time.getStop().isAfter(maxStop)) {
        maxStop = time.getStop();
    }
}
```

EDIT: Ok this is what I've come up with. The idea is to have all times in a list and then sort the list, that way something like this:

```
08:00 -> start
12:00 -> stop
11:00 -> start
15:00 -> stop
09:00 -> start
17:00 -> stop
18:00 -> start
20:00 -> stop
18:00 -> start
21:00 -> stop
```

Becomes:

```
08:00 -> start
09:00 -> start
11:00 -> start
12:00 -> stop
15:00 -> stop
17:00 -> stop
18:00 -> start
18:00 -> start
20:00 -> stop
21:00 -> stop
```

Then you just have to get rid of the in between start and stops that don't matter.

Full code: (ignore all the static shit, it's because I run it from main method)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<ScheduleEntries> times = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<ScheduleEntries> mergedTimes = new ArrayList<>();

    times.add(new ScheduleEntries(LocalTime.of(8, 00), LocalTime.of(12, 00)));
    times.add(new ScheduleEntries(LocalTime.of(11, 00), LocalTime.of(15, 00)));
    times.add(new ScheduleEntries(LocalTime.of(9, 00), LocalTime.of(17, 00)));
    times.add(new ScheduleEntries(LocalTime.of(18, 00), LocalTime.of(20, 00)));
    times.add(new ScheduleEntries(LocalTime.of(18, 00), LocalTime.of(21, 00)));

    // Add all the times in a list
    ArrayList<Time> allTimes = new ArrayList<>();
    times.forEach(time -> {
        allTimes.add(new Time(time.getStart(), "start"));
        allTimes.add(new Time(time.getStop(), "stop"));
    });

    // Sort the list, I used a bubblesort
    boolean sorted = false;
    LocalTime tempTime;
    String tempString;
    while (!sorted) {
        sorted = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < allTimes.size() - 1; i++) {
            if (allTimes.get(i).getTime().isAfter(allTimes.get(i + 1).getTime())) {
                tempTime = allTimes.get(i + 1).getTime();
                tempString = allTimes.get(i + 1).getStartOrStop();

                allTimes.get(i + 1).setTime(allTimes.get(i).getTime());
                allTimes.get(i + 1).setStartOrStop(allTimes.get(i).getStartOrStop());

                allTimes.get(i).setTime(tempTime);
                allTimes.get(i).setStartOrStop(tempString);
                sorted = false;
            }
        }
    }

    // Only keep the relevant times
    LocalTime tempstart;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < allTimes.size()) {
        tempstart = allTimes.get(i).getTime();
        // iterate till you find a stop
        while (allTimes.get(i).getStartOrStop().equals("start")) {
            i++;
        }
        // iterate till you find a start, incase there's several stops in a row
        while (i < allTimes.size() && allTimes.get(i).getStartOrStop().equals("stop")) {
            i++;
        }
        mergedTimes.add(new ScheduleEntries(tempstart, allTimes.get(i - 1).getTime()));
    }

    // Print to check
    mergedTimes.forEach(time -> {
        System.out.println("Start: " + time.getStart() + ", Stop: " + time.getStop());
    });
}

// The class I made to hold the time and wether it's a start or a stop.
static class Time {
    private LocalTime time;
    private String startOrStop;
    public Time(LocalTime time, String startOrStop) {
        this.time = time;
        this.startOrStop = startOrStop;
    }
    // Getter and setter
    public String getStartOrStop() { return startOrStop; }
    public void setStartOrStop(String startOrStop) { this.startOrStop = startOrStop; }
    public LocalTime getTime() { return time; }
    public void setTime(LocalTime time) { this.time = time; }
}
```

Comment: What when we have this case: 1) start: 08:00, end: 10:00. 2) start: 11:00, end: 13:00?

Comment: Updated, hope it helps.